# Contact Account inside a Map of a Map - variable does not exist - account

Tags: apex, map, contact

I want to place leads and contacts within a Map so that I can access them on a visualforce page using a repeat component. Unfortunately I cannot access the Account values from the Contact object when it is inside the map.

Here is the code:

```
public class myController {
  public Contact[] contacts {get;set;}
  public Lead[] leads {get;set;}

  public Map<ID, Lead> leadMap {get;set;}   
  public Map<ID, Contact> contactMap {get; set;}

  public Map<String, Map<ID, sObject>> sections {get; private set;}

  private void getMatches(String searchString){
    contacts = [SELECT name, firstname, lastname, Account.Name, email, HasOptedOutOfEmail, DoNotCall FROM Contact Where Email = :searchString];   
    leads = [SELECT name, firstname, lastname, Company, email, HasOptedOutOfEmail, DoNotCall FROM Lead Where Email = :searchString];
    for(Lead l: leads) {
        leadMap.put(l.id, l);
    }
    for(Contact c: contacts){
        contactMap.put(c.id, c);
    }
}
   private void makeSections(){
    sections = new Map<String, Map<ID, sObject>>{
        'contactMap' => contactMap,
        'leadMap' => leadMap
     };   
  }
}
```

So I run that, and populate the various maps with some leads and contacts.

If I then run:

```
 System.debug(contactMap.get('0030Y00001RJdfOQAT').account.name)
```

I get the correct response (the company name).

But if I run:

```
Map<ID, sObject> myMap = sections.get('contactMap');
sObject myObject = myMap.get('0030Y00001RJdfOQAT');
```

Even though myMap.get('0030Y00001RJdfOQAT') seems to be exactly the same thing as contactMap.get('0030Y00001RJdfOQAT'), if I try to run myMap.get('0030Y00001RJdfOQAT').account.name to retrieve the company name, I get the problem message 'variable does not exist account'.

Why can't I access the account name from the contact within the 'sections' map of maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your inner map is `Map<Id, SObject>` rather than `Map<Id, Contact>`.

There are two ways to work around it:

- Cast the `SObject` to a concrete type (`Contact`)

  ```
  Contact record = (Contact)myMap.get('...');
  String name = record.Account.Name;
  //or just use it directly
  name = ((Contact)myMap.get('...')).Account.Name
  ```
- Use the `get` method on the `SObject` class. Unfortunately this approach does not work with a cross-object get and so you would need to add a bit more logic.

  ```
  SObject record = myMap.get('...');
  SObject parent = record.getSObject('Account');
  String name = (parent == null) ? null : parent.get('Name');
  ```

Comment: This is totally a missed opportunity to throw in a switch statement.

Comment: Thanks Adrian -

For the second method, 

    String name = (parent == null) ? null : parent.get('Name'); 

is giving problem - 'Illegal assignment from Object to String'

Answer (score 0):

You can't access (most) fields on a generic SObject, so you have to use methods like get and getSObject. The cool new Summer '18 way to do this is with a switch statement:

```
sObject myObject = myMap.get('0030Y00001RJdfOQAT');
String name;
switch on myObject {
  when Contact contactRecord {
    name = contactRecord.Account.Name;
  }
  when Lead leadRecord {
    name = leadRecord.Company;
  }
}
System.debug('Found name: '+name);
```

In Visualforce, though, things get a bit... dicey. You need to know what type of record you're working with. In that case, it's probably just better to make a "Wrapper" class:

```
public class RecordWrapper {
  sObject record;
  public String getAccountName() {
    switch on record {
      when Contact conRecord {
        return conRecord.Account.Name;
      }
      when LEad leadRecord {
        return leadRecord.Company;
      }
      when else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
  public RecordWrapper(sobject source) {
    record = source;
  }
}
```

You'd modify your maps accordingly:

```
public Map<String, Map<ID, RecordWrapper>> sections {get; private set;}
```

...

```
for(Lead l: leads) {
    leadMap.put(l.id, new RecordWrapper(l));
}
for(Contact c: contacts){
    contactMap.put(c.id, new RecordWrapper(c));
}
```

This would ultimately simplify your rendering mechanism:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!sections}" var="section" ...
  <apex:repeat value="{!section}" var="record" ...
    <apex:outputText value="{!record.name}" ...
```

You'll need to tweak this a little, but it should be pretty straightforward once you get past the wrapper part.